# How do you get isolated SQL syntax error in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, exception, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy I would like to isolate any SQL syntax errors. For instance..

```
try:
  [row for row in db.execute(text("select * from userds"), **args)]
except ProgrammingError as error:
  print(error)
```

I get

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "userds" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from userds
                      ^
 [SQL: 'select * from userds'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

And I'm only interested in..

```
relation "userds" does not exist
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: `print(error.params[0])` or `print(error._message)`? --> https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L19

Comment: This doesn't work. `error.params` is an empty dict and `error._message` is actually a function that still includes the driver info at the beginning of the line. Thanks for the link to the source though.

Comment: I should note that I am trying to avoid string munging on the error msg bc. the application I am writing can connect w/multi. database drivers dynamically so I don't know in advance the driver..

Comment: you're right I was looking at the source code for `SQLAlchemy` and not `psycopg2` which is what you're using, it should simply be `error.pgerror` as shown here --> http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.Error

Comment: Thanks but I do want it to be independent of db driver.. I was using postgres as an example but it should work for mysql, sqlite etc.

Comment: well drivers handle errors differently in their classes, you will obviously need some sort of function that handles logic based on the driver afaik

Comment: Looks like there is a StatementError you can recover from and print out the `orig` attribute... see below

Answer (score 5):

I have found a solution to my question. You must catch StatementError and print out the `orig` attribute on the error object, like so..

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import StatementError

try: 
 [r for r in db.execute("invalid statement")]
except StatementError as error:
 print(error.orig)
```

https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/699272e4dcb9aa71ebbc0d9487fb6de82d3abc2b/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L280